# Pasar parametro en tarea utilizando lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Tengo esta tardea...

```
    void TareaFecha()
    {
        Task T = new Task(() =>
        {
            DateTime FechaActual = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime Inicio = FechaActual.AddDays(8);
            MessageBox.Show($"TareaFecha, fecha calculada = {Inicio}");
        });
        T.Start();
    }
```

Intento pasarle como parámetro en el paréntesis de la parte izquierda del lambda un numero entero ; `Task T = new Task((dias) =>` para poder utilizarlo después dentro de la función, en la linea ; `DateTime Inicio = FechaActual.AddDays(dias);` y sustituirlo por el numero constante `8` pero no hay manera, con ese tipo de sintaxis, ¿Donde le asigno el valor al parámetro?

EDIT:

Por ejemplo aqui, le paso el parametro sin problema, pero, ¿Por que?

```
    void TareaFechaParametro()
    {
        Task T = new Task((dias) => MessageBox.Show($"TareaFecha, fecha calculada = {dias}"), 4);
        T.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es crear un método externo y llamarlo desde la tarea:

```
void TareaFecha()
{
    Task T = new Task(() => this.SetFecha(8));
    T.Start();
}

void SetFecha(int dias)
{
    DateTime FechaActual = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime Inicio = FechaActual.AddDays(dias);
    MessageBox.Show($"TareaFecha, fecha calculada = {Inicio}");
}
```

Por otro lado, el problema en tu código es que debes pasarle el parámetro al final. Esto debería funcionar:

```
void TareaFecha(int dia)
{
    Task T = new Task((dias) =>
    {
        DateTime FechaActual = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime Inicio = FechaActual.AddDays((Int32)dias);
        MessageBox.Show($"TareaFecha, fecha calculada = {Inicio}");
    },dia);
    T.Start();
}
```

Si ya tuvieran que ser más de un parámetro, la cosa se complicaría.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, conocía esa solución pero me gustaría saber si hay posibilidad de hacerlo directamente con un delegado anónimo, es decir, sin tener que otorgar ningún método. Es mera curiosidad y posibilidad :D
Editado el mensaje original con ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente como ejemplo, para que te puedas guiar

```
//Aquí paso el número con el que deseo trabajar dentro del lambda
Task t = new Task((obj) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
}, 12);
t.Start();
```

Aquí paso 12 como el valor inicial para la variable **obj**, de todo esto lo más importante es que lo que le pasas al lambda es un Object por tanto si vas a trabajar con una clase u otra estructura, recuerda hacer el correspondiente casting.

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solucion seria:

```
Action<int> act = (days) => 
{   
     DateTime FechaActual = DateTime.Today;
     DateTime Inicio = FechaActual.AddDays(days);
     Console.WriteLine("TareaFecha, fecha calculada = "+ Inicio.ToShortDateString());
};

Task.Run(()=> act(2));
```

De esa manera si necesitaras pasar mas parametros solo tendrias que modificar tu action:

ejemplo:

```
Action<DateTime, int> act = (FechaActual, days) => 
{   
     DateTime Inicio = FechaActual.AddDays(days);
     Console.WriteLine("TareaFecha, fecha calculada = "+ Inicio.ToShortDateString());
};

Task.Run(()=> act(DateTime.Now, 2));
```